# Laravel Passing Data from View to Controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.3. I'm trying to pass some input from the View to a Controller. Here is what I am doing now in the View:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/update/company') }}">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
         <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

             @if ($errors->has('name'))
             <span class="help-block">
                 <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
             </span>
             @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Register
                </button>
          </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the route:

```
Route::put('/update/company', [
'as' => 'updateCompany',
'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@update'
]);
```

And here is the Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request){
    $compEmail = $this->companyEmail;
    if( ! $compEmail)
    {
        echo "Email Invalid";
    }

    $user = User::all()->where("email", $compEmail)->first();

    if ( ! $user)
    {
        echo "Invalid Company";
    }

    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->confirmed = 1;
    $user->confirmation_code = null;

    $user->save();

}
```

This is giving me the **error:**

> Creating default object from empty value on the line $user->name =
>   $request->input('name');

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't find any `$user`:

```
if ( ! $user) {
    echo "Invalid Company";
}
```

you're not returning the method so here:

```
$user->name = $request->input('name');
$user->confirmed = 1;
$user->confirmation_code = null;
```

You try to access fields on `null` value from `$user` empty var.

You should add `return` here:

```
if ( ! $user) {
    echo "Invalid Company";
    return;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, but that doesn't fix my original problem that is, how to pass data from the view to the controller.

Comment: You mean from controller to view?

Comment: Yeah, nevermind, I fixed the problem. I wasn't thinking straight